# Constant value android ProgressBar without thread and handlers

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I want to implement constant value android ProgressBar without use thread and handlers. Whenever I search related examples it uses thread and handlers, and without use of thread, handlers OR AsyncTask it doesn't work.

My requirements is to show ProgressBar with fix value range, something like below image:[image]

Please help me with sample code snippet. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the progress bar directly using the ProgressBar API setProgress()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgress%28int%29